# Did any member of the Seljuk dynasty adopt an heir?

Tags: anatolia

There are couple of articles about adoption of children in Ottoman empire, but I couldn't find anything about Seljuk empire. Adoption of children were common then. I would like to know if there is similar case in Seljuk dynasty (who maybe became ruler of some kind)?

Comment: "It was popular adopting children in Seljuk Empire." - What does 'it' refer to? "Adoption of children were common then." - When are you referring to? I think you need to add some more detail to this to make an answerable question.

Comment: [Please document your preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786); please cite the articles.  Review of [Wikipedia:Seljuk_dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seljuk_dynasty) provides the list of rulers; it should be possible to answer the question based on that information.  (or perhaps I misunderstand the question.)

Comment: Under Islamic law, adoption is necessarily an informal practice.  It's explicitly spelled out that it does not trigger incest laws and that the adoptee must continue to be referred to as the son of the biological father.

Comment: Do you have any sources for your claims? Under Islamic Inheritence law, only your biological children are your children. Adopted ones cannot be heirs. So in that sense, it makes 0 sense for dynasties governing their lands by Islamic law to adopt their heirs. Are you sure you aren't mixing it up with Byzantines where adopting heirs was a common practice?